# Is it possible to write a BigQuery to retrieve binned counts of PyPI downloads over time?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, pypi

The following code is an SQL query for google's BigQuery that counts the number of times my PyPI package has been downloaded in the last 30 days.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_downloads
FROM `the-psf.pypi.downloads*`
WHERE file.project = 'pycotools'
  -- Only query the last 30 days of history
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX
    BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE(
      '%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

Is it possible to modify this query so that I get the number of downloads every 30 days since the package was uploaded? The output would be a `.csv` that looks something like this:

```
date          count
01-01-2016    10
01-02-2016    20
    ..        ..
01-05-2018    100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use the EXTRACT or MONTH() and to count only the file.project field as it will let the query run faster. the query you could use is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM _PARTITIONDATE) AS month_, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM _PARTITIONDATE) AS year_,
  count(file.project) as count
FROM
  `the-psf.pypi.downloads*`
WHERE
  file.project= 'pycotools'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER by 1 ASC
```

I tried it with the public dataset:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pickup_datetime) AS month_, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pickup_datetime) AS year_,
  count(rate_code) as count
FROM
  `nyc-tlc.green.trips_2015`
WHERE
  rate_code=5
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER by 1 ASC
```

or using legacy

```
SELECT
  MONTH(pickup_datetime) AS month_, 
  YEAR(pickup_datetime) AS year_,
  count(rate_code) as count
FROM
  [nyc-tlc:green.trips_2015]
  WHERE
  rate_code=5
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  ORDER by 1 ASC
```

the result is:

```
month_  year_   count    
1       2015    34228    
2       2015    36366    
3       2015    42221    
4       2015    41159    
5       2015    41934    
6       2015    39506
```

I see you are using _TABLE_SUFFIX, so if you are querying partitioned table you can use the [_PARTITIONDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#the_95partitiondate_pseudo_column) column instead of formatting the date and using the date_sub function. This will use less compute time as well.

To query from [one partition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#limiting_partitions_queried_using_pseudo_columns):

```
SELECT
  [COLUMN]
FROM
  [DATASET].[TABLE]
WHERE
  _PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01'
  AND '2016-01-02'
```